# The way to check Socks5 RoundtripTime as Ping do

Tags: c#, socks

Im working with `Telegram API`. There I have to use `Socks5` to connect. I have Socks5 list where contains servers and ports. I need to ping them and see which of them are working and also see ping of working Socks5 and what socks are dead now.

> Anybody knows the way how  do this?

Comment: Yes.  Use Ping!!!

Comment: @jdweng Ping() cant ping Socks5. Even in Command Promt Ping cant ping Socks5. There is alsways connection error

Comment: So use the Net method.

Comment: @jdweng whay does it means? If you wants me using System. Net.NetworkInformation - it through exeption  "SocketException: This host is unknown." every time

Comment: Couse I dont think that for example ping 138.68.165.154 and ping 138.68.165.154:8080 is the same thing, or im wrong?

Comment: You do not use the port number 8080 for ping.  Ping just checks the IP address is responding, the TTL (number of hops), and the round trip time.

Comment: FYI, the protocol that the ping utility uses is known as Internet Control Message Protocol - ICMP for short. You can write your own ICMP utilities if you so desire.

Comment: OMG. So I can check port by TcpClient using Connect . Then simply ping Ip Adress